# При наречии "ещё", "не" с причастиями пишется раздельно?

Tags: грамматика

> На непросохшем песке *еще* **не** затоптанные следы крупных капель. ([Бакланов](https://books.google.ru/books?id=7Xd3wRfOgIwC&pg=PT45&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LFy4VNqWK-nMyAPfhIH4Bg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&f=false))
>
> Сизый ковыль, ещё не распустившийся, *ещё* **не** побелевший, расстилался, как волны. ([Аксаков](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ZPGxAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C,%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F,%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9,%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B.&source=bl&ots=FCbk7fqk_A&sig=hitMVve04PGDGfK-Vk8RB0cSzT8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Y1y4VLfqMqaqywPnpYHgCQ&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B.&f=false))
>
> ...тянулись вверх по небу золотые полосы от лучей *еще* **не** взошедшего солнца. ([Куприн](http://lib.ru/LITRA/KUPRIN/nghtlodg.txt_with-big-pictures.html))

В моём учебнике я не нашёл для этого правила, но выглядит будто если есть наречие *ещё*, то **не** с причастиями пишется раздельно. Что меня смущает, потому что я ведь могу сказать *ещё маленький ребёнок*, *ещё свежие овощи*, хотя понимаю что "маленький" и "свежий" являются прилагательными, а не причастиями.

Действительно ли *ещё* является зависимым от причастий словом и, следовательно, заставляет частицу **не** находиться отдельно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Действительно ли *ещё* является зависимым от причастий словом...?

Я думаю, что именно так.

*ещё не затоптанные следы*
*не затоптанные ещё следы*
*не затоптанные пока следы*
*не затоптанные к утру следы*
*не затоптанные прохожими следы*

Кажется, функция зависимого слова налицо.

Примеры *ещё маленький ребёнок* и *ещё свежие овощи* вряд ли хороши, так как не содержат *не-*. Можно предложить более наглядные примеры: *ещё небольшой ребёнок*, *ещё неспелые овощи* -- но *ещё не выросший ребёнок* и *ещё не созревшие овощи*. Тут *небольшой* и *неспелый* -- прилагательные, легко заменяемые синонимами *маленький* и *зелёный*, поэтому они должны писаться слитно. Причастия же с *не-*, согласно правилу о зависимом слове, пишутся раздельно.

Comment: В Корпусе Русского языка по запросу "ещё небольшой" находим 46 документов (http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E5%F9%E5+%ED%E5%E1%EE%EB%FC%F8%EE%E9), по запросу "ещё не большой" -- 0 документов (http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E5%F9%E5+%ED%E5+%E1%EE%EB%FC%F8%EE%E9).

Comment: Также в Google Books по запросу "ещё неспелые" -- 100 документов (https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5%22), по запросу "ещё не спелые" -- 52 (https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5%22).

Comment: С ребёнком и овощами я немного зарапортовался, прошу прощения. Я имел в виду привести антипримеры, но не сопроводил их комментарием. Однако *небольшой* и *неспелый* -- не причастия, а прилагательные, легко заменяемые синонимами *маленький* и *зелёный*. Поэтому они должны писаться слитно. *Ещё небольшой ребёнок*, *Ещё неспелые овощи* -- но *Ещё не выросший ребёнок* и *Ещё не созревшие овощи*.

Comment: @Artemix: Да, пожалуй. Спасибо. Сделал.